# View factory for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, factory

I am trying to create a View factory for iOS and I am getting into some trouble. The view factory should be a able to create multiple UIImageViews, MKMapViews or UIWebViews and add them to a view vertically. I have a problem with the web view cause I have to wait for `webViewDidFinishLoad`. If the methods are implemented in the ViewController which implements the `UIWebViewDelegate` and the delegate of the webviews is set to the controller everything works fine. The thing is that I want to put all of this in a separate class but the `webViewDidFinishLoad` is never been called. Is there a way to achieve that?
Tell me if you need any code

Code:
Part is added

```
- (void)addPart
{
  if (self.viewPartStrings.count != 0) {
    NSString *viewPartString = [self.viewPartStrings objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *viewPartIdentifier = [self getViewPartIdentifier:viewPartString];
    NSString *viewPartDefinition = [self getViewPartDefinition:viewPartString];
    if ([viewPartIdentifier isEqualToString:kWeb]) {
        [self createTextWebViewPart:viewPartIdentifier];
    } else if ([viewPartIdentifier isEqualToString:kMap]) {
        [self createMapViewPart:viewPartDefinition];
    } else if ([viewPartIdentifier isEqualToString:kImage]) {
        [self createImageViewPart:viewPartDefinition];
    }
  }
}
```

Views are created:

```
- (void)createTextWebViewPart:(NSString *)viewPartText
{
    WebViewPart *webViewPart = [[WebViewPart alloc]initWithFrame:[self getViewPartFrameForHeight:0]];
    [webViewPart createViewForText:viewPartText];
    [webViewPart setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)createImageViewPart:(NSString *)viewPartDefinition
{
    //create image
}

- (void)createMapViewPart:(NSString *)viewPartDefinition
{
    //create map
}
```

But here is the point. This method is never called. Not if the class extends NSObject and not if the class extends UIView:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
    int height = frame.size.height + 70;
    [self addToView:webView forHeight:height];

}
```

**EDIT:** I also tried doing this in the Controller:

```
@interface DetailController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewPartsFactory *viewPartsFactory;
@end
```

Then:

```
- (void)setViewForModel:(DealModel *)model
{
    //...
    self.viewPartsFactory = [[ViewPartsFactory alloc]initWithViewParts:                      [descriptionParser getViewParts]];
    UIView *view = [self.viewPartsFactory getView]
    [scrollView addSubview:view];
    //..
}
```

and

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.viewPartsFactory webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
}
```

setting the webview delegates to the controller but still nothing.

Comment: If you could provide at least a high level example in code of how you're doing this, that would help. Hard to understand what your problem is specifically.

Comment: I've added some code

Comment: Ah. Since you're putting this in another class, you'll have to add your own delegate methods in the new class and connect those to the view controller.

Comment: @remus I did that but even if I pass the viewcontroller to the factory (the factory has a strong reference to the controller) and set the delegate to from the webviews to the viewcontroller webViewDidFinishLoad is not called in the controller

Comment: What about making the view controller the UIWebView AND NewClass delegate, and when webViewDidFinishLoad is called, just call your factory class's method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this in super-pseudo code and hopefully it'll give you an idea of what I'm suggesting.

```
// ViewPartsFactory.h

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad; // implement your logic in this method
// Ensure you DO NOT set the delegate anywhere here, otherwise it'll override when you set it in the view controller.

//--------------------------------------------------//

// DetailController.m

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <UIWebViewDelegate> delegate;
DetailController <UIWebViewDelegate>

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.delegate = viewPartsFactory;
}
```

Comment: I tried that out but the webViewDidFinishLoad is never called and I don't know why

Comment: OK, can you add the way you've wired up your delegates to your original question? Don't need any logic, just the declarations in @interface

Comment: Chained delegates always boggle my mind, which is why I always try to avoid them, but see my edit to the question and see if that works. If I'm wrong, then try the opposite.

Comment: Still not working. I suppose I'll look it into the weekend and get back to you :)